# Conifgure VBoxManage commands that require VM be running from Vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

There are several commands under the VBoxManage umbrella that require the guest machine already be running (e.g. controlvm, guestcontrol) but all the vbox configuration I see in the Vagrantfile happens *before* the machine has started.

Is there a way in the Vagrantfile to configure the machine *after* it has started?

Comment: For any searchers who are ok automating VBoxManage commands _before_ boot, see: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/virtualbox/configuration#vboxmanage-customizations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of vagrant is to abstract the creation of VM for multiple provider (including VirtualBox) it is not really to provide all manipulation of the VM afterwards and replace the VBoxManage -

If you need to run command after the VM has started and run it from `Vagrantfile`, I would suggest to look at the [vagrant-triggers plugin](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) which :

> Allow the definition of arbitrary scripts that will run on the host before and/or after Vagrant commands.

Comment: in the meantime, the plugin seems to be [integrated](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/triggers) into vagrant.